Which is the correct way to answer this?
So there's no eggs in the fridge?
No,there isn't
So there's no eggs in the fridge?
No!
So there's no eggs in the fridge?
Yes, there isn't

Try again! . . .

The correct question should be "There are no eggs", to which I would reply "No, there aren't".

There's a lot of information here on responding to negative questions. I linked the highest-voted above, but you can read all the others.
